# Read data from an aux cable

Tags: audio

I have a record player that has a jack for headphone output.  Is there any way that I can plug my computer into it using an AUX cable and read/record the sound data.  My main language is java but any solution or idea would help.

-Windows doesn't seem to recognize the device as microphone input when I plug it in.
-No audio recording software I found seems to recognize it either.
-I know you can take aux input because a square reader works as input on a phone (No idea how)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.